# Tkinter is not a module in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, pycharm, ubuntu-20.04

I was on my computer and I was trying to code some tkinter code but when I put the starters in Pycharm, there was an error saying that Tkinter is not a module and then I tested it as tkinter and it was also not found. Can someone please help me get this sorted out as I really want to do some coding and this is slowing it down.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using python 3? If so you need to use `import tkinter` not `import Tkinter`. That got changed from python 2 to python 3

Comment: You also need Tcl/Tk since Tkinter is a wrapper over those libraries.

Comment: @stark How would I go about installing that?

Comment: @TheLizzard didnt work, still chucking errors at me

Comment: Please post a [MRE] of the programming problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it installed on your OS? You can try `sudo apt install python3-tk` or `sudo apt install python-tk`.

You could also try installing it via pip: `pip install python-tk`

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! It worked very well and now I can code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3, beyond installing with

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

the following will help to get it to work:

instead of
`from Tkinter import *` use `from tkinter import *`

or generic suitable for both Python2 and Python 3

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    from tkinter import *
else:
    from Tkinter import *
```

Similarly:
instead of `import Tkinter as tk` use `import tkinter as tk`

or generic suitable for both Python2 and Python 3

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    import tkinter as tk
else:
    import Tkinter as tk
```